# sed find and replace line containing string after IP address

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

I'm trying to use sed to find a line containing a string after an IP address and replace that line.  To illustrate, I have a text file like so ...

```
192.168.10.155 Mike
8.8.8.8 Googley
123.231.123.3 Tom
192.238.8.10 Matt
```

Let's say I want to find and replace Tom's line, and I want to match on a Tom AFTER an IP address and a space.  Each octet of the IP address could have between 1 and 3 digits.  Currently, I have ...

```
newIpAddress="111.111.111.111"
sed -i "/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3} Tom/c\$newIpAddress Tom" file
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas as to how I could fix that first part to properly match dynamically on any IP address with 1 to 3 digits per octet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -ri "/[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3} Tom$/c$newip Tom" file
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the `awk` approach:

```
$ new_ip=1.1.1.1    

$ awk -v ip="$new_ip" '$2=="Tom"{$1=ip}1' file
192.168.10.155 Mike
8.8.8.8 Googley
1.1.1.1 Tom
192.238.8.10 Matt
```